# removing item in numpy array based on multiple positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of numpy arrays, and want to remove elements based on a specific position.

```
[array([ 1, 2, nan, 4, nan]), 
array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

I need to get the positions of all the `np.nan` and remove the corresponding columns, giving me:

```
[array([ 1, 2, 4]), 
array([ 5, 6, 8]),
array([ 5, 6, 8])]
```

Short of looping everything, I have no idea where to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your list of arrays is named A:

```
A = [np.delete(row,np.argwhere(np.isnan(A[0]))) for row in A]
```

output:

```
[array([1., 2., 4.]), array([5, 6, 8]), array([5, 6, 8])]
```

Depending on your application however it might be better to use sams-studio's approach of creating one large `numpy` array. I would prefer that approach for most applications.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the easiest would be

```py
# arr is your original list
arr = [np.array([ 1, 2, np.nan, 4, np.nan]),
       np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
       np.array([ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
return_array = np.asarray(arr)[:, ~np.isnan(np.asarray(arr)).any(axis=0)]
print(return_array)
```

This will return:

```py
array([[1., 2., 4.],
       [5., 6., 8.],
       [5., 6., 8.]])
```

If you want to have a `list` of `array`, then you have to do additionally:

```py
return_array = [r for r in return_array]
```